# Detect integer overflow in wasm bytecode

Tags: rust, webassembly

I have a wasm binary I am trying to execute in Rust.I am not sure if it has integer overflow Are there any tools that can help me detect integer overflow in Rust itself?

Comment: What does "a wasm binary I am trying to execute in Rust" mean? How do you execute a binary in a programming language?

Comment: Through `Command`.

Comment: Shouldn’t you be debugging the wasm application? The binary will be opaque to Rust if it's executed through `Command`.

Comment: true. If there are debugging tools, it would be great! Couldn't find any.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few methods, that can help you:

- [`checked_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.checked_add) which will perform an addition. If the addition would overflow, it returns `None`, else it returns `Some(sum)`.
- [`overflowing_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.overflowing_add) which will perform an addition and returns a tuple, where the first one is the overflowing sum, and the second element a boolean which indicates whether an overflow happened or not.

You can also check [`saturaing_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.saturating_add) and [`wrapping_add`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html#method.wrapping_add) and see if they fit your needings.